# React Image Container Div Cutting Off

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, image

I have a div element with some images in it, but they get cut off and I was wondering if I could have some help with that?

```
<div className={styles.orgImages}>
  {/* TODO: some of your (Part 1) edits in this vicinity */}
   {!org.image && 
      (<img src="https://1mktxg24rspz19foqjixu9rl-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/eia-berkeley-Cover.png"
        alt="Organization"
      />)          
   }
   {org.image  && 
      (<img src={org.image}
        alt="Organization"
      />)          
  }
  {org.image2  && 
      (<img src={org.image2}
        alt="Organization"
      />)          
  }

</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
  .orgImages {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
  .img {
    width: 50%;
  }
```

So far I've tried adding the width and height attributes. I also tried display block and in-line. I don't know how to fix it and would love some help!

Also if anyone has tips on how to account for 0-2 images that would be great! Ideally if theres 2 images each only takes up half, which is why I was experimenting with the width: 50% tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.orgImages {
    height: auto;
    max-with: 100%;
}
```

I guess, image size is greater than div size and you are using full height and width as you had set height, width 100%. So it cant be fit into the div.

if you want to use 2 adjacent images in that case you can use bootstrap

```html
<div className = "row">
  <div className = "col-xl-6 col-xs-6">
    **//write the code for 1 pic here with above css**
  </div>[enter image description here][1]
  <div className = "col-xl-6 col-xs-6">
    **//write code for 2 pic here with above css**
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can use React-bootstrap it will be quite easy

```html
<Row>
  <Col>
    **//write the code for 1 pic here with above css**
  </Col> 
  <Col > 
    **//write the code for 1 pic here with above css**
  </Col>
</Row>
```

I hope it will help.